# Where/what is the Peer Exchange (PEX) protocol specification for BitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, peer-exchange, peer-discovery

There's a note that BEP 11 is the pending draft for PEX. However this was never published, and there's no official specification that I can find.

Comment: Did you check with the [developers](http://www.bittorrent.org/mailing_list.html)?

Comment: @EmacsUser It's not possible to subscribe to that mailing list. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official specification, but other clients have documented the de-facto standard of the `ut_pex`-over-ltep extension.

http://svn.tribler.org/abc/branches/boudewijn/beps/bep_0034.rst

https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/doc/extended-messaging.txt?rev=7196

---

Update: Now there also is an [official spec](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html).